# Ignoring a folder inside static files using gitignore in a Django project

Tags: django, git, gitignore

I have a folder inside the `static` directory of an app in a Django project. Lets call this `special_folder`. It contains some static files that I do not want to commit to Git. The project directory looks something like this:

```
myproject
|
+-- manage.py
|
+-- .gitignore
|
+-- myapp
    |
    +-- static
        |
        +-- special_folder
```

Now, if I want to ignore this folder for Git, do I need to add something like the following line to the `.gitignore` file:

```
myapp/static/special_folder/
```

Is this the right approach? Or should I just add `special_folder/`? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All paths are relative to the .gitignore.

Based on your folder structure and location of .gitignore file you are correct. The below should work.

```
myapp/static/special_folder/
```

Refer [Pattern Format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

HTH